# Columns merging in external tables

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am currently using external tables to load the data but I see that data for two columns are getting merged when one of the columns gets 'ía' in it. Is there a way to resolve this?

```
create table table_name_ext (
col1 varchar2(20),
col2 VARCHAR2(25),
col3 VARCHAR2(50),
col4 VARCHAR2(25),

)
organization external
(type oracle_loader
default directory table_name_reports
access parameters
(
records delimited by NEWLINE
badfile T_LOG: 'table1.bad'
logfile T_LOG: 'table2.log'
readsize 5000000
skip 1
fields terminated by X'9' LRTRIM
MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
reject rows with all null fields
(
col1 char(20) terminated by X'9',
col2 char(25) terminated by X'9',
col3 char(50) terminated by X'9',
col4 char(25) terminated by X'9',

)
)
location
(
'FileName
)
) reject limit unlimited;
```

Comment: Possibly a character set issue; check the database character set, client encoding, and the encoding of the file. A sample file that produces this effect would also be helpful. (Made-up data is fine, as long as it does actually error when loaded.)

Comment: @AlexPoole- My database character set value is AL32UTF8. The data that I am getting is in .txt files and separated by tab. What do you think would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: I don't know, I can't see how to replicate this. Sample data would help, as would the encoding of the text file.